# Want to make windows application to run on 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: winforms, 32bit-64bit

I am in process of creating an windows forms application and one question has just came up to make my application to run on both 32 bit and 64 bit machines.

I googled my question and found one solution to change the Platform target from 'any cpu' to x86 and then compile it. Then it will work on both systems.

Now here my question is, do i need to do anything else to achieve this or the above solution will be fine.

I am in middle of creating my application so i can not test it now.

Comment: **No, keep "Any CPU"** and it'll be a 32 bit application on 32 bit systems and a 64 bit application on 64 bit systems. If you change to X86 you'll get a 32 bit application. Always.

Comment: AnyCPU is the choice, at least if you don't link your app to a third party software that has only a 32bit or 64bit version.

Comment: Thanks Adriano and Steve for saving me and I belive creating two installer with the correct DLLs will solve my all problems(Suggested by Hans Passant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***solution explorer --> Double click Properties (A new tab should open up) --> build tab***

Setting ***configurations*** to **`'Any CPU'`** ensures that your application will work on both 32 and 64bit computers.

[image: Any CPU]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are three more things you have to do, practical stuff:

1. You'll need to check if you are actually ahead by letting the code run in 64-bit mode.  In general, 64-bit code runs a bit slower than 32-bit code, it uses the CPU cache much less efficiently due to the doubled pointer sizes.  Compensated somewhat by it having 8 extra cpu registers.  You'll only get a perf benefit if you manipulate a lot of values of type long or double in your inner loops.  You *can* get a perf improvement from being able to use a lot more memory but that's pretty hard to achieve if your program must run in 32-bit mode as well.
2. You'll need to *test* your code on both a 32-bit and a 64-bit operating system.  Pretty hard to avoid dependencies on native code, lots of it is buried in wrappers that you might not recognize as native code.  A database provider for example.  Such code comes in two distinct flavors that might not behave the same.
3. If you in fact have such a dependency then you may well need to write two installers that deploy the correct native DLLs on the target machine.  One 64-bit and one 32-bit installer.  Whether you do or not should flush out at bullet #2.

Clearly you want to focus on bullet #1 first, it may well help you skip numbers 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks, I belive 3rd option will be more approchable. Creating two installers with the correct DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a comparison of the options [Any CPU, x32bit, x64bit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/netfx64bit/thread/0b21d7a4-d929-4ac3-8447-f51b9c28ec9c).

> "AnyCPU lets you run in both 32bits and 64bits boxes while x64 can only run in 64bits"

From your post I see no reason to not use `Any CPU`.